# Oracle Incrementally Updated Backups - does "recover copy of database" makes all datafiles consistent?

Tags: oracle, rman

I would like to use Oracle Incrementally Updated Backups on 19c. Using this script to achieve it:

```
RUN {
  BACKUP INCREMENTAL LEVEL 1 FOR RECOVER OF COPY WITH TAG 'mybackup' DATABASE;
  RECOVER COPY OF DATABASE WITH TAG 'mybackup';
}
```

As far as I understand:

On the first run, the "backup" command will only create level 0 copy which is not consistent and the "recover" command will do nothing.

On the second run, the "backup" command will create level 1 backupset and the "recover" command will apply it to the datafile copies.

**The question is :** after the second run, whether the datafile copies will be consistent? Will they startup as a database without applying any additional archives? *(the startup is planned on another server which does not have access to any original files except of the backup directory)*

Comment: See the below link https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/incrementally-updated-image-copy-backups
you have misunderstood the concept.

Comment: @sarat I have read the proposed link several times and I hope that I understood the concept. ...but, can you answer the question in the topic?